# How to be awarded the Cleanup badge?

Tags: support, badges

The [Cleanup](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/4/cleanup) badge is defined by "first rollback". It's not the first delete of a post or a question, but something else - question is what do you have to rollback to get the badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Rollback" refers to edits. So once you've rolled back your own or someone else's edit, you'll be given the badge.

Comment: Thanx! Didn't quite get that from the description, maybe it needs a change? *hint* *hint* :)

Comment: @BennySkogberg The bigger problem is no one goes to the revisions page/knows it exists. The badges are a little vague to encourage poking around in the interface so you learn

Comment: @BenBrocka That's why the badges exist, to guide the user to unknown features, right?